# Javascript empty array object and url parameter

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have this script, which decodes the url and set the value of the asp field with url`s parameter (?lastname=Somebody&phone=12345)

```
        <script>

var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();

    lastname = urlParams["lastname"];
   document.getElementById('ctl00_maincontent_FormView1_FirstNameTextBox').value = lastname;

        </script>
```

How to check if an array element is null and just leave the field blank, instead now i get undefined. I have more than one parameter to check (lastname, name, phone, ect.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like
`lastname = urlParams["lastname"] || '';`

This provides a 'default' if it's undefined